# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null (maps.js line 85 and 541)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, geolocation

I am using geolocations, using AJAX and showing my places on map at my web site. I have an API key and my site is working on localhost perfectly, but when I upload to hosting then I get errors in the JavaScript console:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

My maps.js 85. lines codes...

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

and line 541...

```
placeMarkers(results);
```

Comment: start by pasting your javascript in a syntax checker (there's various online). You've created a variable of the same name numerous times in your script, so either use different var names or define the var once, globally.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your markers array is undefined. Is this something returned by your geolocation. If yes, make sure that is defined and has some values in it before the for loop.